# Show that $T=I-2\frac{vv^t}{v^tv }$ is an orthogonal operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $T=I-2\frac{vv^t}{v^tv }$ is an orthogonal operator in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and how to find it's eigenvalues?

I can't see what's the way to start. I have seen that if $\|T(x)\|=\|x\|$ then it's enough, is it?

Comment: $Tx = x - \langle x, \frac{v}{|v|} \rangle\frac{v}{|v|}$. So $Tx$ subtracts the component of $x$ in the direction of $v$. Assuming $v \neq 0$, $T$ is not orthogonal since $Tv = 0$.

Comment: Any chance you meant $T=I-\color{red}{2}\dfrac{vv^t}{v^tv }$?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes it's using 2

Comment: Go ahead and calculate $T^t T$

Comment: @Thomas Ready! It's $I$. Could you tell me how to approach the eigenvalues?

Comment: @Thomas should I just solve $Tx=\lambda x$? for some $\lambda$

Comment: Write down $T-\lambda I = 0$ and try to find $\lambda$?

Comment: Hint: apply $T$ to $v$ and then to some $w$ orthogonal to $v$. (That is actually a spoiler).

Comment: You can use Cauchy's determinant formula: $\det(A + xy^*) = \det(A) + y^*\operatorname{adj}(A)x$ to find the eigenvalues.

Comment: once you recognize $T$ is real symmetric and orthogonal, its eigenvalues are completely specified by the trace

Comment: @Valent Why are you considering eigenvlaues? The **definition** of an orthogonal operator is either an operator $T$ for which $T^tT = I$ or an operator for which $\|T(x)\| = \|x\|$ (for all $x$).